# Why is fuzzy_like_this returning results from all types?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am surprised that `fuzzy_like_this` doesn't seem to be scoped to the index and type I'm searching. Instead, I get results from ALL types in my index. I am searching with `fuzzy_like_this` against a type, specifically `/places/places_city/_search`. Unfortunately it appears to return results from all types in the index, which seems like a bug.

I have been trying by prefixing my fields with `places_city` but this is not  working.

My code is given below

```
{
              "constant_score": { // here i am using this because to remove tf/idf factors from my scoring
              boost: .001,
                "query": {
                  "fuzzy_like_this" : {
                    "fields" : ["places_city.city"],
    //              "fields" : ['places_city.city'],
                    "like_text" : "bangaloremn",
                    "prefix_length": 3,
                    "fuzziness": 2
                  }
                }
              }
            }
```

Here i have places_city as type name and city as its field i was using this typename.field convention in a normal query and it was working perfectly fine   for **below query** but i don't know why it is not working inside fuzzy like.

```
"must": [
                  {
                    "constant_score": { // here i am using this because to remove tf/idf factors from my scoring
                      boost: 1.04,
                      "query": {
                        query_string: {
                          query: location_search,
                          fields: ['places_city.city'],
          //               boost: 1.04
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
```

Here ES is referencing to places_city as type name and city as its field but its not doing that in above code.

Comment: can you edit your question to incnlude a sample doc? Do you mean the "search type" as in what you place in the URL? Like "people" in the Elasticsearch URL `/company/people`?

Comment: i have index as merchants now inside it i have types "places_city" and city is the field name

Comment: sorry i dont get what yu are trying to say ??

Comment: {"took":3,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":5,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"places","_type":"places_city","_id":"AVAIlotZBRFxLL5AtKXE","_score":1.0,"_source":{"city":"Bangalore"}},{"_index":"places","_type":"places_city","_id":"AVAIl2tnBRFxLL5AtKXH","_score":1.0,"_source":{"city":"Delhi"}},

Comment: Is this Elasticsearch's [nested documents features](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-nested-type.html)? Or is it a subdivision of an index, like your would add a new document with a `PUT /merchants/places_city/1`?

Comment: So you're saying you're surprised Delhi matches when you search for Bangaloremn?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90755/discussion-between-aman-verma-and-doug-t).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90756/discussion-between-aman-verma-and-doug-t).